# incompatable HDD connector?

Tags: hard-drive, desktop, connector

I bought an old pc (HP, winxp, Intel 4, 2.8 GHz, 256MB ram) with a dead hdd (it booted up at the thrift shop, but it's giving me a smart error now). I have a spare drive that I was going to swap in, and install linux, but my drive, that I've been using as an external backup drive until now, is missing the four pin power connector that this old pc utilizes (I think it's called a molex?). Is there a way to use my hdd in this pc? preferably without buying anything? (I already sunk 75 bucks in this thing, and I think I paid too much, even with the lcd monitor, keyboard and optical mouse included).

Ps. I bought this thing so that I can introduce my grandmother to computers (my grandfather already has a laptop). Oh, and both hdds are 3.5

edit: after a second look, the other connection is also completely different. At the very least, I think I'll need a new set of cables or some adapters. Will that work?

The old HDD:

[image: Old HDD]

The intended replacement drive:

[image: SATA HDD]

UPDATE: I did a system restore to manufacturer's settings (or whatever you call it) and managed to recover the hard drive. So it works now I guess. I also tried lubuntu on an external hard drive through usb. The result, this fossil doesn't have enough processing power to run a browser in lubuntu, and the original os updates through IE, which for some reason won't connect to the internet (I have another question open for that issue), and even if I can get it updated (I'm going to try, as an experiment), I doubt it can actually run the latest version of xp (which is still obsolete) or any semi-modern software.

The verdict: Unless you're trying to open a museum, don't buy 15 year old pcs. This thing is basically a doorstop. (according to a google search, I might be able to use it as a home server or a cctv system if I buy some cameras, but I have my doubts). Lesson learned.

Comment: A picture of the HDD connector, the exact model number of the HDD, the exact model number of the external enclosure are all required to help you.   SATA HDDs don't use a molex connector they use [SATA power](https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.tL_bBAUiydE9VOjb7CfQgQEsDL&pid=15.1).

Comment: alright, give me a few minutes to take the pictures and transfer them to my pc, and I'll add them.

Comment: P4, WinXP, PATA drives... yeah... you spent way too much:/ 10 bucks max, preferably free. [& I sincerely hope the 256MB RAM is a typo, that won't run any recent OS]

Comment: ram can be replaced, and I was thinking more around $50. a new pc (and not a high performance rig, btw) will run from $400 to $800, used, we're looking at $200 to $300, so for an old model, $50 seems fair. $75 is definitely too much, but whatever.

Comment: RAM can be replaced. But a P4 probaly used DDR or DDR2, not the DDR4 stuff which you find in shops these days. And it might not support exotic big DIMMs. (and 512MiB would be exotically big for that era). Also you will need to buy a new OS. XP simply is not an option anymore. Not if you want to connect it to the Internet or any other network. And the new OS might not work with ancient hardware.

Comment: yeah, I intend to "buy" lubuntu. It's not that old. you're acting like it's a 98. xp was dominant until like 3 years ago.

Comment: Tom hardware usually has some up to data builds. The lastest one seems to be here. http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3314070/builds-2017-500-budget-category.html.  That is US$500 / €467 for a system which is way way way way more powerfull, uses less power and has an insanely faster graphics card. If you replace Tom expensive card with an modern €30 card you will in the the USD400 range with everything dozens of times better. And if you scrape the barrel you can even save on that.

Comment: XP was end of life 2009. That is 6 years ago. EOL got postponed a few times but these days you do not get updates for it. Which includes security updates. So XP is certainly usable, just do not use any network and glue over the USB ports. And yes, that would make it mostly useless. Lubuntu ect would work though, but seriously, 75 euro for initial, plus some more memory, ples a convertor, plus lots of time...and you are already spending a about half of that a 15 year more modern system can do. And the new system does not have to replaced quite as soon.

Comment: I just saw your edit: Confirming now. MOLEX&PATA vs SATA(and SATA power)

Comment: why would I glue the usb ports? plug&play devices and flash cards work fine. That's the only thing I've ever used a usb drive for. (that, and a network card on my old xp, years ago). I didn't know about the ddr though. After a search, it seems I'll get 2 gigs tops. This pc will only be used to browse the web, but still, 2g is definitely low for a desktop.

Comment: Risk of infection from/to the XP system. And yes, I already read you consider Lubuntu. Both for XP I always suggest it if only to get people thinking before they keep using XP for internet banking, amazon shopping etc.

Comment: -1 Your title is completely wrong, there is no missing hdd connector here. One hard drive is a PATA hard drive, the other is a SATA hard drive. That's all. Simple as that.  Some older motherboards only support PATA, some less old motherboards support both. And modern motherboards only support SATA.  And if the hard drive is in that sense "incompatible" and you want to plug it in then you can use an adaptor, they're often cheap.

Comment: 75 bucks could have bought you something like a quad core Q6600, on a mobo that can take DDR3 & SATA, making your entire integration into a 'modern' computing system very simple. It would also run anything up to Win 10. Honestly, I'd write it of as a "learning curve" & get something built less than a decade ago. [Ref: I do this for a living, & have done for 15 years]

Comment: where? I can't find any used PC's online for less than $120-$150 bucks minimum. After some testing though this fossil is definitely unusable.

Comment: @barlop wtf is wrong with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your motherboard. Older motherboards generally only have IDE/Molex connections, while newer motherboards are SATA-only.

It sounds like your computer only has 4-pin Molex for power, which would mean it only has support for IDE drives (IDE data cables are wide, flat, and usually gray):
[image: IDE ribbon cable]

You most likely will have to purchase an adapter  cable for the power connection, something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Molex-Power-SATA-Female-Adapter/dp/B000YJMB5Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJMB5Y)

You will also need an adapter for the data cables, like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Generic-IDE-SATA-Adapter/dp/B000RK89M4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RK89M4)

EDIT: My bad, the adapter above for the data cables is for the other direction (IDE drive to SATA motherboard)
This product looks like it should work for you. It's an adapter for both data and power in one, so you will only need to purchase this (Disclaimer: never tried it):
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002Y2NI4M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Y2NI4M)

Comment: will it work with these adapters? pic's added, btw.

Comment: See edit. Just use the adapter between the existing IDE/Molex cables in your system and the new drive

Comment: The only answer that both solved my problem without ridicule. thanks. After some testing, This thing isn't worth the investment, but that's something that I can easily discern for myself. I had an xp that worked well, and I ran it until the hard drive crashed a few years ago. If it still ran (I don't have it anymore, btw), it would have no problem with minor browsing and light applications. I made the mistake of comparing this piece of garbage to my old xp. This thing is completely unusable.

Answer (score 0):

> The four pin power connector

This probably is indeed was usually is called molex. If you add a pciture than we can verify that. As a help until then, red wire, yellow wire and two black wires in the middle?

And the ages of that PC (A pentium 4, that is 2004-ish?) it probably shipped with either a classic IDE/ATA drive. Which these days is called PATA. It used a molex for power and a 40 or 80 pins wire for data. (The 80 pins wire was 80 pins plus additional grounds for improved shielding).

Alternatively it might have had SCSI (also molex for non server models, but with a 50 or 68 pins cable. Server models often used SCA with integrated power).

Since then we have moved away from both SCSI and paralel ATA. SCSI moved to SAS, P ATA moved to SATA. The data connectors from these are quite different, and that will be your main problem.

Power remained more of less the same. It got a new for factor where the ground makes contact first. But it still is +5 and +12v volt and ground. A simple Molex to SATA power convertor should be easy to find.

(BTW, some early SATA disks used the old molex power and new data connector).

[image: MOLEX and PATA connectors]

[image: SATA connectors (both power and data]
<sup>Source: Wikipedia</sup>

> Is there a way to use my hdd in this pc? preferably without buying anything?

If the old drive is IDE/ATA and the new one is SATA: No. You would need either a SATA connection (e.g. an add-in card) or a SATA to IDE active part. And you problably would have to buy that.

> (I already sunk 75 bucks in this thing, and I think I paid too much,

Aye. These days I expect to pay people to dump a P4. P4's were horrible. They used a lot of power, they ran very hot, and yet they were not fast. Intel mobile chips from the same era ran at about half the clockspeed, used less than half the power and were nearly as fast. P4 was a disaster. What you really want is a core2 or better.

> even with the lcd monitor, keyboard and optical mouse included).

If the LCD is not bad you could reuse that.

But as for the P4, your options are:

1. Find a working ATA disk. (getting rare, and 200MB PATA is relative large, so expect to find a small disk at a non-trivial price).
2. Find a PATA to SATA convertor. Those could be as cheap as EUR 10.
3. Find a SATA or SAS HBA, Might be hard to find a PCI card these days (assuming that a system this old has PCI and not yet PCI-e).
4. Buy a faster computer for a lower price. Seriously, Eur 5 for a P4 would be too much.

Comment: I might take it back for a refund :/

Comment: I would recommend that, and looking at ebay prices for my current standard old boxen (thinkpad r61's are great, cheap granma machines with a ton of potential) you overpaid. I've pulled better machines from a dumpster. For that matter, I consider a core 2 duo + 1gb of ram + sata a *minimum* to 'bother with' in most cases. Not to mention PIVs were notoriously inefficient. This thing also ran DDR1 (we're at the transition from DDR3 to 4) so other upgrades will be difficult. *AND* probably not even USB 2.0 (will it usb boot?). Yeah, you'd be throwing good time, and money after bad

Comment: I didn't overpay. I got shafted. It will usb boot though, for what it's worth (literally nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Your title is completely wrong, there is no missing hdd connector here. One hard drive is a PATA hard drive, the other is a SATA hard drive. That's all. Simple as that. Some older motherboards only support PATA, some less old motherboards support both. And modern motherboards only support SATA. And if the hard drive is in that sense "incompatible" and you want to plug it in then you can use an adaptor, they're often cheap.

Comment: From the fact that he's asking the question, he obviously was not aware of the existence of PATA and SATA interfaces...hence in his eyes, he's "missing a connector". You're right, it's not accurate, but no reason to attack him for lack of knowledge, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @wysiwyg  Even with a lack of knowledge, and especially with such a lack of knowledge,  he should not have presumed it was "missing a connector"

Comment: A mismatched connector then? What should I have assumed? regardless of the reason(hardware incompatability) the connector that I needed was missing. how much more simply can I put it?

Comment: I mean seriously, I just paid for someone's garbage. give me a ******* break.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barlop, the title is wrong. There is nothing missing.

As stated you have 2 different HDD from 2 different aras (IDE/PATA and SATA) One is Parallel and the other Serial. You need one of those devices shown, essentially a controller card to interface between the on-board PATA and the new HDD's SATA disk controller. In the photos that wysiwig and Hennes show I would stick with something like the one by Generic. Visually it looks much higher quality (not that looks are always a good determination) and it keeps the power and data separate. The power only requires an adapter cable. I have used both of these devices and cables.

Maybe you should keep this for yourself. It looks like a good learning experience. Does not sound like you have heard of online auction sites like eBay. Many use this very site for a good indication of what computers and computer parts are worth as you almost instantly see what others around your country are willing to pay for them. Sometimes they are not willing to pay much if anything.  I have almost 20 old systems that people have given me and when I check online. For instance, I have several systems with higher specs than this one (2-2.5Ghz cpu, 2-4GB DDR2, with SATA)and they sell for $35-75. Just food for thought.

The processing power should be just fine for running a browser as browsing software does not require much cpu power in itself. You have be trying to open something that utilizes flashplayer and don't have the latest updates on that add-in or module. Windows XP is a lost cause unless you update the RAM even though I have gotten XP with service pack 1 and (I think even SP2) to run on 256MB of RAM but it takes an awefull lot of back-end tweaking and is not for the average person unless you want to go after the fulfilling accomplishment of solving huge pc puzzles.

If you udon't upgrade RAM
256Mb of RAM may run Puppy Linux just fine but you need an OS with a small footprint specifically designed to run on older hardware Like Puppy is designed to do.

Comment: The title is not "wrong". Regardless of the reason (hardware incompatibility), the connectors that I needed to install a newer hard drive in this dinosaur ARE missing. If I new WHY this was the case, I would not have needed to ask the ******* question in the first place.

Comment: Also, I cant find **** for less than $120-$150 minimum, and even if I could, I'm not going to buy anything else that isn't at least close to modern (so at least ddr3 and a decent processor). This thing was an impulse buy, intended for an older relative, to get them accustomed to computers. At the time, I thought that it would be sufficient for some minor browsing (my old similarly aged xp was capable of that only 4 years ago before the hard drive crashed and I got something better). Unfortunately, this thing is a piece of garbage.

Comment: @SebastianHahn Missing suggests that it should be on that device but isn't there.. for example, i've seen RAM that was missing a chip, a manufacturing error.  Your hard drive has a  different connector that you didn't seem to be familiar with.  So it  should've been fairly obvious  to you that that hard drive was never meant to have the newer style of connector. You should've enquired about that connector you didn't recognize, rather than saying or suggesting that it had a hdd connector missing, which is just untechnical and nonsense.

Comment: Sebastian, I an other suggested the Title was wrong merely since that system you posted on NEVER had them to beginning with, hence they could NOT have been missing because they never existed. Nobody was trying to be a smart or clever. We only mentioned it so you would think to edit the title so as to facilitate better site indexing so that others could more easily find the info. Also I do not know what "Find ******" refers to specifically. Were you saying you had an similar XP machine you were still browsing with 4 years ago? Similar as in 256MB of RAM?

Comment: I cannot find used pcs selling for under $120-$150 minimum. I said that I had a similarly aged xp (one that came out around the same year, maybe even earlier). I had forgotten, however, that the old xp that I inherited from a parent was actually top of the line for it's time. Also, neither of you mentioned that I should change the title, you were simply being pedantic. But I guess I will change it since NOW you've brought it to my attention that doing so might be a good idea.

Comment: I am surprised you 'cannot find used pcs selling for under $120-$150 minimum'. I have a couple local stores that have many good quality, reconditioned pc's for between $75-150 and there are always deals on eBay. Do you live in an area where an online seller can not ship to you? Thanks for updating the title. Always better to come from the author. The site tutorial kinda explains how everything works and comes together.

Comment: no local stores where I live. I have to shop online. laptops on ebay are a bit cheaper I guess. at this point I'm replying because it would be impolite not to, but I've heard that comment sections aren't for extended conversation, so I'm not going to reply again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use my hdd in this pc?

The old hard drive is IDE.  The newer one you have is SATA.

If there is a company still making IDE drives, they are probably super expensive.  SATA started taking over IDE around 2003-2004.  All modern motherboards have SATA ports.

The good news is that if your system has these type of slots (called *PCI slots*):

[image]

you can add SATA ports by looking for a SATA PCI card.  Most adapters of this type will let you boot off of attached drives like the motherboard ports.  RAID SATA PCI cards are very common.

[image]

**You need to make sure you get a PCI card and *not* a PCI-Express card.  Your system is likely too old to have PCI-Express sockets and they are different and one will not work with the other.**

You will also have to buy a newer power supply that has SATA power connectors.  This is where you may run into trouble as many systems by OEMs such as HP, Dell, etc. from that era have proprietary power supplies - either the shape of the power supply is different or even might have special connectors to the motherboard.

You can look online for an "ATX Power Supply" and if it looks like it will fit in your case, you can upgrade it.

Standard power supplies typically plug into the motherboard with a 20-pin connector (now 24-pins) and there is also a separate power connector that plugs in near the CPU.

If the plugs on your current power supply do not look like this (minus the SATA power connector) ...

[image]

then you will need one of these, and the name of this adapter is "Molex to SATA Power Adapter":

[image]

Then you are really going to have to max out the RAM on that for it to be anything resembling useful.  I would bet that motherboard maxes out at 2GB of RAM.  The RAM on that system may be so old that new RAM of that type may be expensive.

I would scrap this system and chalk it up to a learning experience unless you can get your hands on some other old junk computers to get additional parts.  Anything without SATA ports on the motherboard is definitely too old to be usable these days.

Comment: Thanks for the info. but your last comment is right on the mark. This thing is unusable. I'm not going to invest any more resources into it.